# Could I install Delphi and my libraries on a USB key in such a way as to allow debugging of my app on a customers PC?

Tags: delphi, debugging, usb-drive

Back in the days of Delphi 7, remote debugging was mostly ok. You set up a TCP/IP connection, tweaked a few things in the linker and you could (just about) step through code running on another PC whilst keeping your Delphi IDE and its libraries on your development PC.

Today, with Delphi XE2,3,4 you have paserver which, at least at the moment can be flaky and slow. It is essential for iOS (cross platform) development, but here at [Applied Relay Testing](http://www.appliedrelaytesting.co.uk) we often have to debug on embedded PC's that run recent Windows. To do this we have employed a number of strategies but the hardest situation of all is to visit a customer site and wish that one could 'drop in' a Delphi IDE + libraries and roll up ones sleeves to step through and set breakpoints in source code.

It is quite likely - hopefully - that the paserver remote debugging workflow and its incarnations will improve over time but for now I got to wondering how it might be possible to install Delphi + libraries + our source code on a USB key so that with only a minimal, perhaps automated setup, one could plug that key into a PC and be compiling, running and debugging fairly quickly.

I can see that the registry is one of the possible issues however I do remember that Embarcadero once talked about being able to run their apps from a USB key. Knowing how much of a pain it is to install my 20-odd libraries into Delphi though, it is not trivial and needs thinking about.

Has anyone done anything like this or have any ideas of how it might be done?

Comment: For Win32 Targets you can still use the old style remote debugger.

Comment: Just another thought: perhaps a Delphi via AppWave might help here. You can try with the RAD Studio XE4 Instant Trial: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/RAD_Studio_XE4_Instant_Trial_FAQ

Comment: @Uwe That's interesting, I'll take a look, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delphi does not support what you are asking for.  But what you could do is create a virtual machine with your OS, IDE, libraries etc installed in it, then copy the VM onto a USB drive, install the VM software on the customer system, and run your VM as-is.  There are plenty of VM systems to choose from.

Comment: This won't help if your goal is to debug on the client's machine

Comment: Could you be a little more specific as to why not?

Comment: Because the app is not runnning under the clients OS unless you either run Delphi under that OS or use remote debugging.

Comment: You'd just be debugging on the virtual machine. You may as well sit in the client's office with your laptop and do your debugging that way. That would be equally ineffective! You want to debug the process running the client's machine. Either run Delphi on target, or remote debugging. Running Delphi in a VM doesn't help at all.

Comment: The only difference is that it's a little easier to connect to the clients network and databases from the VM than from a laptop brought in - practically and from a security standpoint (for the OP and the client; the VM is better contained than the laptop).

Comment: @Jan Debateable. Most admins will treat an alien machine exactly the same, be it virtual or physical.

Comment: @David Thinking back, we have used Delphi in a VM and accessed the host machine hardware by setting the correct VM virtualisation, but one would need a host that supported good VM hosting.

Comment: You are still executing the program on a different machine.

Comment: On the other hand, maybe the client app can be installed into the VM for debugging. And some VMs do support debugging a virtual process from a host debugger, and even debugging a virtual process from another VM running on the same host. So there are possibilities, depending on which VM and which Host are used.

Comment: @Remy Since Brian wrote the app, I don't think he needs to visit the client's site to install the app that he wrote. The most plausible reason for debugging on the client's machine is to solve an environmental problem.

Comment: Typically the debugging is only needed to solve real-time issues of control and timing in special cases that have not been reproduced 'at home'. Sometimes it is the only resort to debug and confirm faulty hardware.

Answer (score 3):

First, I need to get this out of the way: embedded PCs running *Windows*?? Sob.

Ok, now for a suggestion: if a full virtual machine isn't an option for this task, application-level virtualization may be. This intercepts registry calls and other application-level information and maps them to a local copy, allowing essentially any application to be turned into a portable version. The good news is that there are free versions of several programs that can turn Windows programs into virtualized apps.

The only one I've personally used is MojoPac, and found it delivered as promised although was very slow running off of a (old, very slow) flash drive.
http://lifehacker.com/309233/make-any-application-portable-with-mojopac-freedom

I haven't used this newer "freedom" version though.

Two other programs I've seen that appear to be popular are Cameyo:
http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/create-your-own-portable-virtual-version-any-windows-program.htm

and P-Apps,
http://dottech.org/26404/create-a-portable-version-of-any-software-with-p-apps/

but I can't vouch for the quality of either of these two.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What's wrong with embedded PCs running windows?  I maintain fifteen industrial production machines, all of which have PLC control systems with Windows-based HMIs.  I think the conveniences outweigh anything that might be construed as a drawback by a long shot - especially when I can, VPN, VNC, debug, recompile, and restart production from my kitchen table on a Saturday.

Comment: @J... the issue wasn't so much with the embedded part as with the Windows part. :-)

Comment: @alcalde Yes, you were very clear - I'm asking you to justify your comment.  If there is a legitimate reason for it to be in your answer then please provide at least some evidence, reasoning, and uses cases where it is a problem.  Otherwise, if it is just irrational fanboyism, it should probably be removed from the answer as irrelevant.